# When importing Excel data, there is a transformDateTime error

Tags: laravel

I'm attempting to import Excel using the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Vch;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithBatchInserts;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Imports\HeadingRowFormatter;

HeadingRowFormatter::default('none');

class VchImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithBatchInserts, WithChunkReading
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */

    private function transformDateTime(string $value, string $format = 'd-m-Y')
    {
        try {
                return Carbon::instance(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($value))->format($format);
            } 
            catch (\ErrorException $e) 
            {
                return Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $value);
            }
    }
    
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Vch([
            'no_vch' => $row[1],
            'nilai_vch' => $row[2],
            'batch' => $row[3],
            'expired' => $this->transformDateTime($row[4]),
            'nama_penerima' => $row[5],
            'alamat_penerima' => $row[6],
            'status' => $row[7],
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I try to import Excel, there is an error like this:

```
App\Imports\VchImport::transformDateTime(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type string, null given, called in C:\Apache24\htdocs\gmpro-dev\app\Imports\VchImport.php on line 41
```

I've tried changing the date format via code, excel, and the computer still doesn't work.
[image]

I'm debugging with `dd($row);` and get this result: row (4) it's supposed date:

```
array:10 [▼
  0 => null
  1 => "CP/WS-GADD/III/23-MR001799"
  2 => 100000
  3 => "0269"
  4 => 45366
  5 => null
  6 => null
  7 => "Beredar"
  8 => null
  9 => null
]
```

**The answer is:** Change your excel format from `.xlsx` to `.xls`.

Comment: In the value parameter you pass a null value, its probably because in the imported Excel there is an empty data in $row[4]. There are several way to handle this, but first check the Excel file

Comment: the value of ` $row[4]` is null .  put `dd($row)` at the first line of model method to debug it.

Comment: I'm edited my question for detail and debug @zohrehda

Comment: Please check my question for more detail @Telexx

Comment: The first row is empty? Can you attach the excel file?

Comment: Before I upgraded my php, it was running normally with that format @Telexx

Comment: In my opinion the problem is that somewhere in the excel in $row[4] there is an empty data

Answer (score 1):

the `model` method runs on every row of excel file . so when you get dd of row
the result is belongs to first row of excel and maybe the problem is caused by another row .

the obvious cause of this error is that in one row of excel the 4th row is empty. so you need to handle this exception :

```
 public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Vch([
            'no_vch' => $row[1],
            'nilai_vch' => $row[2],
            'batch' => $row[3],
            'expired' =>$row[4]? $this->transformDateTime($row[4]):null,
            'nama_penerima' => $row[5],
            'alamat_penerima' => $row[6],
            'status' => $row[7],
        ]);
    }
```

or another way:

```
 private function transformDateTime(string $value=null, string $format = 'd-m-Y')
    {
        if (!$value)
         return null ;

        try {
                return Carbon::instance(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($value))->format($format);
            } 
            catch (\ErrorException $e) 
            {
                return Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $value);
            }
    }
```

Comment: 1. I tried first method doesn't work and give this error: `syntax error, unexpected token ":", expecting "]"`
2. Then I tried second method doesn't work too, each of row null that imported give `0` value.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this error by validating the rows by `WithValidation` concern. you can define rules, ex:

```
  public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            '4' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

By define this rules the $row[4] cannot be empty

With the `SkipsOnFailure` concern you get control over what happens the moment a validation failure happens by the `onFailure` function

```
public function onFailure(Failure ...$failures)
    {
        // Handle the failures how you'd like.
    }
```

or just use the `SkipsFailures` trait.

Your first row is empty, you should use the `WithStartRow` concern, and define the startRow function like this:

```
public function startRow(): int
    {
        return 2;
    }
```

With this the import begins from the second row, jumped out the empty row, or another solution

```
private function transformDateTime($value, string $format = 'd-m-Y')
{
 if(!is_null($value)){
        try {
                return Carbon::instance(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($value))->format($format);
            } 
            catch (\ErrorException $e) 
            {
                return Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $value);
            }
 }
 else{
  Handle if the date is null!
 }
}
```

Handle in the code if the date is null, in this way you can avoid the error

Comment: Can you give me more specifics about where I put that?

Comment: Inside the import class, implement SkipsOnFailure concern, if you implement this concern, you have to define OnFailure function, or the SkipsFailures trait. If you define the OnFailure function you can handle the validation errors (validation error appers when date field is empty), ex insert the today`s date instead of null, or whatever you want. If you use the SkipsFailures trait, it just simply skip the whole row where error appears.
Read more: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html

Comment: This code previously worked fine, before I moved to a new PC and upgraded to PHP 8 and Laravel 8. Is there anything I missed in the installation and upgrade?

Comment: I don't think so, it's a simple error, the function expect a string, but a null given. Are you sure there is no empty space in row 4 in the whole excel file?

Comment: Please check my question above, I edited with excel file.

Comment: Do you have any advice for handling the date while it is null?

Comment: You can insert a null, and there is no expiration date, or define a default expiration date.
ex the default expiration date is a month from now, than:

 `return Carbon::now()->addMonths(1);`

It depends on your application

Comment: No expiration date, I want to handle with today date. What code did I make for it?

Comment: If there is no expiration date, you want to save the today`s date into the Vch, i am right?

If yes, then
 return Carbon::now();

Comment: Doesn't work! The code give this https://prnt.sc/DkCImUbWix15

Comment: I am edited my last comment, first i missunderstand you

Comment: You know this error is due to my Excel format. I changed from `.xlsx` to `.xls` and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

My Excel is clean. No code and no formula. This error is due to my Excel format. I changed from `.xlsx` to `.xls` and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your attention.